# I installed Hyper-V in my virtual machine. I restarted my machine for the installation to get completed, and it is not working ever since

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v

[image]
It required a restart so I did that and since then my machine has asked for an installation twice and even after doing that, my device shows this:
what should I do to move further with Hyper-V?

[image]

This was the last screen before the restart

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to install hyper-v inside virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is a Type 1 hypervisor (or a bare metal hypervisor). It needs hardware virtualization extensions provided by hardware manufacturers like Intel or AMD (VT-x / AMD-V). The CPU and the chipset provided by virtual box cannot  have those extensions (due to various reasons) and that's one among many reasons Hyper-V cannot run inside virtual box.

If you want to test Hyper-V, I'd recommend testing it on bare metal.